# Why are my Subreport and Main Report returning different data?

Tags: jasper-reports, datasource, crosstab, subreport

I’ve used a *crosstab* in the *Summary* band of my *Subreport* to create a dynamic column/pivot table. When I run this independently its working fine and is returning the data correctly, as expected.

Then when I reference it in another report as a *Subreport* within the *Detail* Band, it runs okay with no errors, but with some of the data is missing.

I’m using the same data source for both reports.

*Subreport data expression is*: **`$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "mySubreportFile.jasper"`**
*Connection type*             : **Use a datasource expression**
*Datasource expression*       : **`$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}`**

Can anyone advise please? Unfortunately for security reasons, I cannot provide any files to look at.

Comment: IMHO, the cause of problem can be that the master report and subreport are using the same dataset (iterator).

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'm fairly new to iReport as you can probably tell. Should I be using a different connection type then? How do I get the data to pass to the main report from the subreport? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the *Java* code?

Comment: Hi Alex I am using Java, however due to time constraints I had to find a work around, which meant that I ended up not using a subreport after all. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your main report, are there groups? Your subreport could be restricted to data for that group.

Comment: Thanks Lisa, my main report is not using any groups.

Comment: If you're passing any parameters to the subreport, you might want to display them in the detail band for troubleshooting.